# Javascript Split URL

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I want to SPLIT some specific parts of the URL, here is what i have so far.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var query = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
query = window.location.pathname.split( '.html' );

var redirectpath = "http://www.mydomain.com/search/?q="
window.location.href = redirectpath + query;
</script>
```

**The URL structure will be like this:**

```
http://www.mydomain.com/page/2013/05/some-page-title.html
```

The variable `query` outputs like this;
`page,2013,05,some-page-title`

i only want the `some-page-title` part and also remove the hyphens.

so the final output would be `http://www.mydomain.com/search/?q=some page title`

how is that possible? Please help!!
Thanks

Comment: Split the `pathname` by `"/"` and store in `query`. Take the last item in the array (`var page = query.pop();`) and remove the ".html": `page = page.replace(/\.html$/, "");`, then replace "-" with " ": `page = page.replace(/-/g, " ");`, then make the final string: `var redirectpath = "http://www.mydomain.com/search/?q=" + page;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Split returns an array, use it as an array!

```
var parts = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var query = parts[parts.length-1].split( '.html' );

query[0]= query[0].replace(/-/g," ");   

var redirectpath = "http://www.mydomain.com/search/?q="
window.location.href = redirectpath + query[0];
```

This assuming you always want the part of the url after the last `/`

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your answer and add just the hyphens removal :)

Comment: ^ you guys are Awesome ;) I've bookmarked this post to come back later a vote-up for you guys (*cause i don't have reputation to vote up*)

Answer (score 1):

```
//get the url
                                var url = window.location;
                                //function to get the hostname and pathname
                                //var l = getLocation(url);
                                //split the pathname by /
                                var array = url.pathname.split('/');

                                //fix the url protocol and hostname for concate
                                var pathnames = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;

                                //loop to get the splited url pathname and insert the each url in specific div
                                for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {

                                    //concatenate the path for each loop
                                    pathnames = pathnames + '/' + array[i];

                                    //appending an ancher tag with href for path in the element with id table_panel_header
                                    $("div#table_panel_header").append(
                                            '<a href="' + pathnames + '">'
                                                    + array[i] + '</a>/');
                                }

                                //example text  seen as: Complaint_Module/master/complaint-items/

                               /* example  href will append like
                               <div id="table_panel_header">
                                <a href="http://localhost:8010/Complaint_Module">Complaint_Module</a>/
                                <a href="http://localhost:8010/Complaint_Module/master">master</a>/
                                <a href="http://localhost:8010/Complaint_Module/master/complaint-items">complaint-items</a>/
                                </div> */
```